# Get current week's day and time outside the loop

Tags: date, date-time, timezones

I am trying to get the current week's day and time based on WordPress time settings. So for today, I want to output `Friday` and `2:56 PM` for the time.

The `the_time('l')` and `the_date('d')` functions seems to be only working when in the loop, I could use `date('l')` but what if the php time is different than the time user sets in WordPress settings, could that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`current_time`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_time) to output the time based on the timezone set on the blog's General Settings page.